# Sotez Forge Method Returns "Type Error: Expected String"

Tags: operation

I haven't been able to find example usage of some of the methods available in Sotez, so I've been looking at other implementations and learning as I go. I am currently working on forging a transaction so that it can then be signed and broadcasted. I can't seem to get the Forge method to work, though, and I am thinking it's because I have a problem in my operation object.

```
let operation = {
    kind: "transaction",
    source: "tz1htPf3VPXrHBTX1E7y3tBteib6hA9Teosj",
    fee: "50000",
    counter: "31204",
    gas_limit: "200",
    storage_limit: "0",
    amount: "100000000",
    destination: "tz3WXYtyDUNL91qfiCJtVUX746QpNv5i5ve5"
}

sotez.rpc.getHead()
    .then(head => {
        sotez.tezos.forge(head, operation)
            .then(result => console.log(result))
    })
```

Returns `TypeError: Expected String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation should look like:

```
const operation = {
  branch: 'BLDnyGuzjz6TuDvxgBtHUZmvY2zZqJ7VShDjZsHsxXQtnzrCrPf', // current head hash
  contents: [{
    kind: 'transaction',
    source: 'tz1htPf3VPXrHBTX1E7y3tBteib6hA9Teosj',
    fee: '50000',
    counter: '31204',
    gas_limit: '10200',
    storage_limit: '0',
    amount: '100000000',
    destination: 'tz3WXYtyDUNL91qfiCJtVUX746QpNv5i5ve5',
  }],
};

sotez.rpc.getHead()
  .then(head => (
    sotez.tezos.forge(head, operation)
      .then(result => console.log(result))
  ));
```